# Autocomplete: show not completed characters in a different color

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, autocomplete

I'm trying to make a autocomplete search using ajax.I want that characters arent required yet to come up with different color(black).

```
<script>
function showResult(str) {
  if (str.length==0) { 
    document.getElementById("livesearch").innerHTML="";
    document.getElementById("livesearch").style.border="0px";
    return;
  }
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {  // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (this.readyState==4 && this.status==200) {
      document.getElementById("livesearch").innerHTML=this.responseText;
      document.getElementById("livesearch").style.border="1px solid #A5bCB2";
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","livesearch.php?q="+str,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
<body>

<form>
<input type="text" size="30" onkeyup="showResult(this.value)">
<div id="livesearch"></div>
</form>

</body>
```

My livesearch.php looks like:

```
    echo "Tirana";
    echo "Tepelene";
    echo "Korca";
   echo "Skrapar";
```

For exhample:(photo)

[image]

Can you please help me!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try `$('.ui-autocomplete').css('color','red');` to color red

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a basic example for what you are trying to do :

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 
    /* initially hide product list items */
    $("#dino-list li").hide();
 
    /* highlight matches text */
    var highlight = function (string) {
        $("#dino-list li.match").each(function () {
            var matchStart = $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf("" + string.toLowerCase() + "");
            var matchEnd = matchStart + string.length - 1;
            var beforeMatch = $(this).text().slice(0, matchStart);
            var matchText = $(this).text().slice(matchStart, matchEnd + 1);
            var afterMatch = $(this).text().slice(matchEnd + 1);
            $(this).html("<em>" + beforeMatch + "</em>" + matchText + "<em>" + afterMatch + "</em>");
        });
    };
 
 
    /* filter products */
    $("#search-dinosaurs").on("keyup click input", function () {
        if (this.value.length > 0) {
            $("#dino-list li").removeClass("match").hide().filter(function () {
                return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf($("#search-dinosaurs").val().toLowerCase()) != -1;
            }).addClass("match").show();
            highlight(this.value);
            $("#dino-list").show();
        }
        else {
            $("#dino-list, #dino-list li").removeClass("match").hide();
        }
    });
 
 
});
```

```css
input[type=text]{
  width:200px;
  padding:8px 10px;
}

li{ list-style-type: none; }

li em {
  font-weight:bold;
  font-style:normal;
}

ul {
   padding-left: 10px;
   background: yellow;
   top: -15px;
   position: relative;
   width: 214px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="search-dinosaurs" placeholder="Search for Dinosaurs (start typing)" />
 
<ul id="dino-list">
  <li>Diplodocus</li>
  <li>Stegosaurus</li>
  <li>Triceratops</li>
  <li>Pteradactyl</li>
  <li>Tyrannosaurus Rex</li>
  <li>Protoceratops</li>
  <li>Iguanadon</li>
  <li>Velociraptor</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You mean javascript ?

Comment: this it's not the solution because i want that not completed characters to be in differenc color.

Comment: check it now. If that's not what you want, can you elaborate what else you want ?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
var pattern = "(^|\s)(" + str+ ")(\s|$)";
var regexp = new RegExp(pattern,"ig");
this.responseText.replace(regexp, '$1<b>$2</b>$3');
```